# AS3: Issues with multiple save/load slots

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to take this very simple "game" and give it three save/load slots.  Following a separate tutorial I can make it work with a single save slot but once I try adding more, it gives me the following error message.

1046:Type was not found or was not compile-time constant: save2.

1046:Type was not found or was not compile-time constant: save3.

I am new to actionscript 3 so I'm sure I'm being very newbish but I have tried to figure this out for quite some time now but just can't seem to.  The whole thing is controlled by buttons already placed on the scene.  I appreciate any help I can get.

The code:

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;

var saveDataObject:SharedObject;
var currentScore:Number = 0

init();

function init():void{

btnAdd.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addScore);

btnSave1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save1);
btnSave1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveData);

btnSave2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save2);
btnSave2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveData);

btnSave3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save3);
btnSave3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveData);

btnLoad1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save1);
btnLoad1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadData);

btnLoad2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save2);
btnLoad2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadData);

btnLoad3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save3);
btnLoad3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadData);

}

function save1(e:MouseEvent):void{
saveDataObject = SharedObject.getLocal("savefile1");
}

function save2(e:MouseEvent):void{
saveDataObject = SharedObject.getLocal("savefile2");
}

function save3(e:MouseEvent):void{
saveDataObject = SharedObject.getLocal("savefile3");
}

function addScore(e:MouseEvent):void{
currentScore += 1;
updateScoreText();
}

function saveData(e:MouseEvent):void{
saveDataObject.data.savedScore = currentScore;
trace("Data Saved!");
saveDataObject.flush();
trace(saveDataObject.size);
}

function loadData(e:MouseEvent):void{
currentScore = saveDataObject.data.savedScore;
updateScoreText();
trace("Data Loaded!");
}

function updateScoreText():void
{
txtScore.text = ("Score: " + currentScore);
trace("Score text updated");
}
```

Comment: where did you place those functions? In a class? In same class? It looks like compiler can't find those functions... Weird that it works for save1 and not when you add more. I think your question lacks some key element to understand what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it works like a charm...

Anyways, I've made a simpler version that doesn't use so many functions and Events.
Here is a pure AS3 version of it (just save it as Test.as3 and use as Document Class in Flash), but you can copy the content of the `Test()` method and paste in a action frame.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.SharedObject;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        public function Test()
        {
            /***** START: Faking buttons and field *****/
            var txtScore:TextField = new TextField();
            addChild(txtScore);

            var btnAdd:Sprite = new Sprite();

            var btnSave1:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var btnSave2:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var btnSave3:Sprite = new Sprite();

            var btnLoad1:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var btnLoad2:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var btnLoad3:Sprite = new Sprite();

            var items:Array = [btnAdd, null, btnSave1, btnSave2, btnSave3, null, btnLoad1, btnLoad2, btnLoad3];

            for (var i:int = 0; i < items.length; ++i)
            {
                var item:Sprite = items[i];

                if (item)
                {
                    item.graphics.beginFill(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
                    item.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 25);
                    item.graphics.endFill();

                    item.x = 25;
                    item.y = i * 30 + 25;

                    addChild(item);
                }
            }
            /***** END: Faking buttons and field *****/

            var saveDataObject:SharedObject;
            var currentScore:Number = 0

            btnAdd.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addScore);

            btnSave1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save);
            btnSave2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save);
            btnSave3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save);

            btnLoad1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, load);
            btnLoad2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, load);
            btnLoad3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, load);

            function getLocal(target:Object):String
            {
                if (target == btnSave1 || target == btnLoad1)
                {
                    return "savefile1";
                }
                else if (target == btnSave3 || target == btnLoad2)
                {
                    return "savefile2";
                }
                else if (target == btnSave2 || target == btnLoad3)
                {
                    return "savefile3";
                }
            }

            function save(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var local:String = getLocal(e.target);
                saveDataObject = SharedObject.getLocal(local);
                saveDataObject.data.savedScore = currentScore;
                trace("Data Saved!");
                saveDataObject.flush();
                trace(saveDataObject.size);
            }

            function load(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var local:String = getLocal(e.target);
                saveDataObject = SharedObject.getLocal(local);
                currentScore = saveDataObject.data.savedScore;
                updateScoreText();
                trace("Data Loaded!");
            }

            function addScore(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                currentScore += 1;
                updateScoreText();
            }

            function updateScoreText():void
            {
                txtScore.text = ("Score: " + currentScore);
                trace("Score text updated");
            }
        }
    }
}
```